# How do I overcome error 'Avoid using JavaScript keyword as "v-on" value'

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

How do I get rid of this error in my App.vue component?

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/App.vue
>     Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
>
> C:\xampp2\htdocs\exchproto\src\App.vue
>       15:69  error  Avoid using JavaScript keyword as "v-on" value: ""  vue/valid-v-on
>
> ✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

I tested the whole code (including sub-components) with CDN pull of vuejs/vuetify css/js etc and all worked well. This error only comes up as I am breaking down the code into components and doing everything by "yarn install". Been poking at it for some time with no luck.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
   <v-app-bar app>
    <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click="drawer = !drawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>

    <v-menu :offset-y="true">
     <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <v-btn icon v-on="on">
        <v-icon>mdi-dots-horizontal</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
     </template>

     <v-list>
      <v-list-item v-for="(item, i) in rightMenuitems" :key="i" @click="">
       <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item>
     </v-list>
    </v-menu>
   </v-app-bar>
   <!--router-view></!--router-view-->
  </v-app>
 </template>

 <script>

  export default {
   name: 'App',
   components: {},
   data() {
    return {
     drawer: false,
     rightMenuitems: [
      { title: 'Choice 1' },
      { title: 'Choice 2' },
      { title: 'Choice 3' },
      { title: 'Choice 4' }
     ],
    }
   }
  }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have an empty `@click=""`  You must have the click point to a function:

```html
<v-list-item
    v-for="(item, i) in rightMenuitems"
    :key="i"
    @click="doSomething($event, i)"
>
    <v-list-item-title>
        {{ item.title }}
    </v-list-item-title>
</v-list-item>
```

```js
// ...
    methods: {
        someFunction(event, i) {
           console.log("clicked item " + i);
        }
    }
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove 'click event' and add `to` property in `v-list-item` where `v-for` is being used.

**Note:**
You can bind links with the `to` props, and also links in every objects of `rightMenuitems`.

Here is an example:

[image]